# add column names when using pandas.Dataframe remove rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I do the following, I get a dataframe with the dictionary keys as headers and the values in a row:

```
d = {'a':['a'], 'b':['b'], 'c':['c']}
pd.DataFrame(d)

    a   b   c
0   a   b   c
```

If I do the same but add column names, the dataframe is empty...

```
d = {'a':['a'], 'b':['b'], 'c':['c']}
pd.DataFrame(d, columns = [1,2,3])


  1   2   3
```

Why?

Comment: cheeky: `pd.DataFrame(d).set_axis(range(1, len(d) + 1), axis=1, inplace=False)`

Answer (score 2):

This happens because, in your data `d` there are no values/column names with names `1`,`2`, and `3`.
From pandas doc, the parameter columns:

> columns : Index or array-like
>   Column labels to use for resulting frame. Will default to RangeIndex (0, 1, 2, …, n) if no column labels are provided.

Here you can see all three cases:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d) #Uses default method for columns
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  a  b  c
```

Passing RangeIndex values to `columns`:

```
d = {'a':['a'], 'b':['b'], 'c':['c']}
pd.DataFrame(d, columns = [1,2,3]) #These values are not the RangeIndex values, but label values
```

Output:

```
Empty dataframe #Because there's no columns names 1, 2, or 3
```

Passing the Index values to `columns`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns = ['a','b','c'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  a  b  c
```

Comment: Okay, I tried to do something that I thought was possible but in that case there is no alternative to renaming the dataframe columns once it is created.

Comment: You can rename the columns with `df.rename(columns{'original_name':'new_name"})`

Comment: you need replace a,b,c by 1,2,3 in your dict if you don't want to use rename function

Comment: Yes, OP, maybe you could try and be more clear with are you trying to achieve? Do you wish to know why did you get an empty dataframe with the code you used, or are you trying to rename the columns of your dataframe?

Comment: @Celius: I think I am explicit enough: Why do I get these results doing this? Now I understand. Thank you

Comment: also you can use df.columns= [0,1,2] instead rename function

Comment: Ah, you are right ansev, I'll delete the comment. Understood OP. Glad we could be of help

Answer (score 2):

**this happens because you are reindexing the columns of your dataframe to [0,1,2] and the values ​​really exist in 'a', 'b', 'c', then you need:**

```
d = {'a':['a'], 'b':['b'], 'c':['c']}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

   a  b  c
0  a  b  c
```

---

```
df.rename(columns={'a':0,'b':1,'c':2},inplace=True)
print(df)

   0  1  2
0  a  b  c
```

**Also you can use:**

```
df.columns=[0,1,2]
```

---

```
d = {'a':['a'], 'b':['b'], 'c':['c']}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
   a  b  c
0  a  b  c
```

---

```
df.columns=[0,1,2]
print(df)
   0  1  2
0  a  b  c
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't rename the column you set new ones up, try:

```
d = {'a':['a'], 'b':['b'], 'c':['c']}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
```

---

```
df.rename(columns = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3})
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice didn't see that.